# What approach we should follow to create relationship between two microservices without duplicating?

Tags: microservices, relationship

Microservice architecture is docker-based, one microservice(transaction database with userId) is in Node JS, and the other is in Rust language(User database). We need to create a common API or function to retrieve data from both microservices. MongoDB is used as Database for both microservices.

Answer (score 1):

There are several approaches to do that.

One possible solution is that one of the microservices will be responsible of aggregate this data so this microservice will call the other to obtain the data and then combine it with its own data and return it to the caller. This makes sense when the operation to be done is part of the domain of one of the microservices. For example, if the consumer needs user information it is normal to call the user service and this service makes whatever calls are needed to other services to return all the information.

Another possibility is to use the BFF (Backend For Frontend) pattern, this makes sense when the consumer (for example a frontend) needs different information from different domains to populate the UI, in this case, you will create an additional service that will expose an API with all the information needed for the consumer and this service will do the aggregation of the information. In certain cases, this can be done directly in the API gateway if you are using one.

The third way is similar to the first one but it needs to duplicate data so I don't know if it will be suitable for you. It consists of having a read-only copy of the data owned by one of the service in the other service and updates it asynchronously using events when this data is modified. The benefit of this approach is the performance will be better because you don't need to make the communication between services. The disadvantage is eventual consistency.

Comment: The first approach means you are calling the user microservice in the transaction microservice using code, but what if the database has huge numbers of rows. Or we can use rabbitmq for both services still, I am not sure this will solve my problem.

The second approach causes extra efforts for development and debugging.

The third approach is not suitable for me.